# How to smooth Sound effect looping in LibGdx?

Tags: libgdx

I am using the sound interface in LibGdx to play mp3 audio files. And when choose to loop playing the sound more than one time using `sound.loop();` it works but with small silent period of time every time the sound replayed. So Is there any ways to get rid of this silent period or to play sound effects more smoothly than the one I use?

here is my code:

```
Sound accelarating_sound1;
    accelarating_sound1 = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("speedUp.mp3"));
    accelarating_sound1.loop(1,f,0);
```

Comment: Jusst to be sure: Does your sound support looping, meaning no silent period at the end (many sounds have that) and the end is the same as the beginnning so that you don't hear the "jump" from end to start.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, and just to clarify, I'm using an .mp3 file which support loop (Nothing in the start and end). Making it a .wav will increase the size from 850kb to almost 9mb, so i'm guessing that's not an option for me as well.

Comment: Just an FYI, I use `ogg` files and didn't experience this problem (decoding/start/end gaps).

Answer (score 2):

MP3 files have some decoding(?) delay at the start, using WAV files will give you larger filesizes but don't seem to have that delay.

Its weird that libgdx lets you set whether a track is looping, but doesn't buffer the start of the track when its almost finished.

My answer is a quick fix for small sound effects since I'm having the same problem too, except with a looping piece of music. Making it a WAV will take too much space.

Answer (score 0):

Sound should be only used for short files (couple of seconds). If your file is longer than that you should use the Music class.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone faces similar problem, I had this problem also and using `.ogg` music files instead of `.mp3` solved it.